# Find foreign key relationships with a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to find foreign key relationships with a SQL query?

The database is external to me and I am unable to access it directly to see the links through Server Management Studio.

Comment: Finding metadata is very specific to your RDBMS. What database engine are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it's SQL Server 2008 if that helps

Comment: Try running stored procedure called `sp_help` on the table the relationships of which you'd like to explore, like this: `sp_help my_table`. You should get back seven result sets describing the table. The last one should have information about table's foreign keys.

Comment: actually you can find the foreign keys and and primary keys fairly easily using a query.

Comment: You can run a query to see relationships, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No you cant,

But you can check it manually,it is cumbersome where you need to query each table and to check what are the columns[id's] exist in each different tables. To see it's relationships.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, the database consists of 560 tables so I might just give it a miss then!

Comment: it is much better if you can access the server in your sql management studio and you can use views to see the relationship of all tables in the database you are accessing.

Answer (score 11):

To retrieve a list of Foreign keys, you can run this query:

```
SELECT t.name AS FKTableName
   , fk.name AS NameOfForeignKey
   , pc.name AS FKColumn
   , rt.name AS ReferencedTable
   , c.name AS ReferencedColumn
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS fk ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON fkc.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS rt ON fkc.referenced_object_id = rt.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pc ON fkc.parent_object_id = pc.object_id
   AND fkc.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON fkc.referenced_object_id = c.object_id
   AND fkc.referenced_column_id = c.column_id
```

This query can also be made more complex if you require additional information for your setup.

Answer (score 3):

To find about foreign keys, consider using these system views:

```
sys.sysconstraints
sys.columns
sys.tables
```

You can join these three views on colid, column_id, object_id to get full information about the foreign key constraints.

These views should be in SQL Server 2005+